# Why is this line included in the `logcheck` report email?

Tags: regular-expression

In addition to the Debian provided rulesets, I have added a file /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/wpasupplicant.local (owner root:logcheck, mode 0644) to my newly installed logcheck setup. I have confirmed that REPORTLEVEL is set to "workstation" in /etc/logcheck/logcheck.conf. The contents of wpasupplicant.local is the single line:

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ wpa_supplicant\[[[:digit:]]+\]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX \[GTK=CCMP\]$
```

where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the lowercase-hex MAC address of my WiFi AP/gateway.

However, I'm still receiving email reports hourly (every time logcheck executes) which include the following (the time varies; I have set up rekeying to be done at fairly short intervals):

```
Aug 11 20:06:51 yeono wpa_supplicant[2524]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX [GTK=CCMP]
```

Again, XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the lowercase-hex MAC address I'm connecting to. I have double-checked that the MAC addresses shown are the same in both.

If I do `grep -E --color "$(cat wpasupplicant.local)" -` and then paste the log line copied directly from the log email into grep's stdin, it indicates a full match (the entire line is echoed back at me, colored red).

Since the data does match something in the proper `ignore` directory, I would expect that line to not be included in the e-mail report. I have checked /etc/logcheck/violations.d and /etc/logcheck/cracking.d and neither seems to contain anything relevant (`grep -i WPA *` in those two directories turn up empty).

**What might be the reason why the "rekeying completed" line is included in the logcheck report e-mail?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading `README.logcheck-database`:

```
Another safety-net is provided by the fact that the process that
collates all the applicable rules uses "run-parts", the standard
Debian utility also used for iterating through "/etc/cron.d",
"/etc/ppp/ip-up.d" etcetera.  It therefore automatically ignores
files with names such as "fooserver.disabled" or "local~".
```

I'm not sure if the `.local` extension is making logcheck skip your `wpasupplicant.local` file, does it work without the `.local`?

Comment: Renaming the file to `wpasupplicant.<myhostname>` didn't do anything. However, naming the file `wpasupplicant-<myhostname>` or `wpasupplicant-local` *does* appear to work the way one would expect. Seems like it is the `.` that something doesn't like.